# Java: Generate certificate (X509Certificate object) from PrivateKey object

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, rsa

I have a class which loads a PrivateKey object as follows from a private RSA key string:

```
    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(privKeyString.getBytes());
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(spec);
```

I think the above will work to get a PrivateKey object. However, once I have a private key, I would also like to generate a X509Certificate object from it. This was one of my attempts, but the method generateCertificate expects an input stream (containing the certificate from a file, I believe.), so this won't work:

```
    CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate cert = f.generateCertificate(privateKey);  // this doesn't work.
```

Is there a way to create a certificate (ideally that doesn't expire) from a PrivateKey object only or from the private key string I had originally (privKeyString variable)?

Thank you,

Comment: I should also mention that I am using a private key string that is in the following format: 
http://ospkibook.sourceforge.net/docs/OSPKI-2.4.7/OSPKI-html/sample-priv-key.htm

I am not sure whether I need to remove the "BEGIN" and "END" comments at the top and bottom and do a base64.decode prior to using the string as an argument in X509EncodedKeySpec.

Comment: You are using wrong terms, hence the problems. You don't "generate" the private key from the privKeyString but load the key. Well, you can neither generate nor load the certificate from what you have. You need to determine what exactly you need first.

Comment: and what do I need first exactly? If a public key is required to make a certificate, then I can generate a public key from the private key. That's the question I'm asking, what do I need to generate the certificate?

Comment: Nothing. You need nothing. "Certificate generation" includes generating a keypair and filling extra fields (Subject Name, Issuer Name, Key Usage etc) to make the certificate.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. So I'll require the certificate to be passed along with the private key.

Comment: if you want someone to pass you his private key, then this is wrong - the private key is kept secret by its owner. What are you going to do with the certificate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The typical flow of events is something like the following: You generate a keypair, which means a private key and a matching public key. The private key is yours and you never share it; that's why it's called private. The public key is what you give out to others. One common format for publishing a public key is an X.509 certificate. This certificate contains the public key plus some identifying information. This certificate can be self-signed, or it can be signed by another authority.

Unfortunately, the standard Oracle Java libraries do not contain any classes to assist you in generating an X.509 certificate from a public key. You can use a command-line tool that comes with the Oracle JDK called [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) to accomplish this. If you must do this programmatically then the [Bouncycastle Java libraries](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) contain some classes to accomplish this. For example, the [JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/cert/jcajce/JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder.html) is probably the simplest way to accomplish this task, together with the [JcaContentSignerBuilder](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/operator/jcajce/JcaContentSignerBuilder.html) class.

Here is an example using Java 7 and Bouncycastle version 1.50 provider and PKIX libraries.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.ContentSigner;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;

public class CertBuilder {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Generate a keypair

        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(1024);
        KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();

        // Start creating a self-signed X.509 certificate with the public key

        X500Name subjName = new X500Name("C=US, ST=NY, O=Certs_R_Us, CN=notreal@example.com");
        BigInteger serialNumber = new BigInteger("900");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(2014, 6, 7, 11, 59, 59);
        Date notBefore = cal.getTime();
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 10); // Expires in 10 years
        Date notAfter = cal.getTime();
        JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder x509Builder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(subjName, serialNumber, 
                notBefore, notAfter, subjName, kp.getPublic());

        // Create a signer to sign (self-sign) the certificate.

        JcaContentSignerBuilder signerBuilder = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WITHRSA");
        ContentSigner signer = signerBuilder.build(kp.getPrivate());

        // Now finish the creation of the self-signed certificate.

        JcaX509CertificateConverter converter = new JcaX509CertificateConverter();
        X509Certificate mySelfSignedCert = converter.getCertificate(x509Builder.build(signer));

        // Now create a KeyStore and store the private key and associated cert.

        final char[] password = "password99".toCharArray();
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ks.load(null, password);

        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privKeyEntry = new KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry(kp.getPrivate(), 
                new Certificate[] {mySelfSignedCert});
        ks.setEntry("myRSAkey", privKeyEntry, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password));

        // Now save off the KeyStore to a file.

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("MyKeys.jks");
            ks.store(fos, password);
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```